# Joomla: How can I add custom field in banner component?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I want to add a custom field in banner component on admin side **without editing the core files**.

I tried with a plugin described [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin) to do this.
but I am not getting any extra field there.

Is there any other way to add a field in banner component?

Comment: Where is the code you first tried with? Without editing core files the only method you have is creating a custom plugin.

Comment: have you checked [template overriding] (https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

Answer (score 0):

Create a plugin like this:

```
class PlgContentExtraField extends JPlugin
{
  protected $autoloadLanguage = true;
  function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data) {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $option = $app->input->get('option');
    switch($option) {
      case 'com_banners':
      if ($app->isAdmin()) { // assuming backend
        JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');
// loading file extra.xml from subfolder /forms in your plugin folder
        $form->loadFile('extra', false); 
      }
    }
  return true;
  }
}
```

and with a description-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.1" type="plugin" group="content" method="upgrade">
    <name>plg_content_extra</name>
    <author>Jonas</author>
    <creationDate>Sept 2015</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2015</copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
    <authorEmail>xxx@gmail.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl></authorUrl>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <description>Example plugin</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="extra">extra.php</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

The file forms/extra.xml could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form> 
  <fields name="params" >
    <fieldset name="image" >
      <field name="extra_field" type="text" label="An extra field" /> 
    </fieldset>
  </fields>
</form>
```

Install the plugin using the discovery-function in the admin interface, and remember to enable it.

Now: where the field shows up depends on the structure of the forms xml-file in com_banners. You find this file in /administrator/components/com_banners/models/forms/banner.xml. In the example  above I placed the extra field in fields params and fieldset  image. These fields are displayed in the tab called Details in the banner forms interface. You could place the extra fields other places instead, but you have to make sure it is actually displayed somewhere. It is also possible to override the admin template to make sure the extra field is displayed like you want it.